# How to get one product to modify information in the cart in Shopify?

Tags: shopify

If a customer clicks a certain button in my Shopify store, I'd like to be able to add information to my cart using Liquid (or whatever is needed).  This information can be as simple as a string.  The customer won't see this information, but it will be used to modify the look of the cart page.  I can happily parse it/handle it as a string, if that's my only option, but so far I can't get any information to be sent.  I have tried modifying cart.note using a `{% capture %}` block, but that never ended up modifying anything permanently.  I also am not sure how to change `line_item` properties, but that might do it as well.

Comment: For either one, you will need to post the updated information to an appropriate cart endpoint.  `{% capture %}` isn't interactive, that's just a multi-line variable assignment.

Your main three options for storing the info are line-item properties, cart notes and cart attributes.  Can you describe what you're trying to do a little bit more?  I have a feeling that setting a cart attribute is what you'll want to do :)

Comment: Thanks.  I have a "box" that customers fill with items (like a bundle sale).  Customers can fill multiple boxes.  Boxes and items are both products in the store - customers can purchase individual items, or put them into a box for a discount.  I'd like to allow the customers to click "add to box" on a product page, and an appropriate note gets added to the cart (or the box's line_item itself, doesn't matter much to me) indicating "Product X in box Y"

Comment: Customers can purchase various boxes, which are limited in terms of the types of items/size of items that goes into each one, which is why it's possible for a customer to be buying multiple boxes and therefore have to choose which box it goes into

Comment: Then line item properties are probably the way to go - is everything being added to the cart all at once? Are you manipulating items that are already in the cart? Some combination of both?

Comment: It will be added to the cart separately.  So for example, a customer can add a box, then start filling it with individual items.  A customer cannot fill it with items already in the cart, though.  So they cannot add a bunch of items, then decide to add them into a box.  Therefore there will always be at least one box in the cart if they want to add to a box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can add input fields with the name `properties[some-prop-name]` to your product form, which would include the required linking data**

For example, adding the following input to your product form would add a line-item property to your product as you add it:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="properties[_add_to_box]" value="{{ box_identifier }}" />
```

---

**If you want to dynamically update line-item properties to add/rearrange items in boxes post-hoc you can do so using AJAX requests targeting the `/cart/change.js` endpoint**

Here's an example of such a command, which you would run upon the user changing the appropriate input element:

```js
/* Assuming we have a variable named cart (containing the cart JSON) and the the 0-based index for the item we want to update */

var line = index + 1;  //Shopify uses 1-based indexing for line-items
var qty = cart.items[index].quantity;

jQuery.ajax({
  url:'/cart/change.js',
  type:'post',
  dataType:'json',
  data:{
   line: line, /* Line to edit: REQUIRED */
   quantity: qty, /* 'New' quantity - If omitted, the line will change to quantity 1! */
   properties:{
     /*
      This properties object will replace any existing properties object on the line-item, so be sure to include everything, not just what you're changing!
      Properties with keys that are prepended with an underscore (_) are hidden in Shopify's checkout page.  
     */
     _box_id: 'box01',
     'Congratulatory Message':'Hooray! You did it!'
   }
  },
  success:function(cart){
    console.log('Success!', cart)
  },
  error:function(err){
    alert('Something went wrong!', err)
  }
 
})
```

Hopefully this helps you get your feature in!

Comment: Whoops - apparently I misread your comment as customers CAN fill with items already in the cart

Comment: Why does it have to be a dynamic update? Submitting the form from the product page should just work fine?

Comment: Because I misread the comment and thought they wanted to add Things to Boxes _after_ both the Thing and the Box were in the cart :P

Comment: Just checking: when I make a new line item property, can I then just update it without AJAX?

Comment: If you want to edit the line item properties of an item already in the cart, you need an AJAX call to `/cart/change.js`. If you want to add a new item to the cart and put the line-item properties at the time of addition, simply include those properties as fields in the form that you're submitting to `/cart/add`.  Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

You can store that data in the line item properties.

[Get customization information for products with line item properties](https://help.shopify.com/themes/customization/products/features/get-customization-information-for-products)

> You can collect customization information for products using line item properties. Line item properties are custom form fields that you can add to the product page, allowing customers to make choices or add information about a product. For example, if you offer product engraving, then you can use line item properties to let customers enter the text that they want engraved on the product.

Then you can access the line item properties from your liquid template.